# Entity Framework Update-Database issues

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have been using Entity Framework Code First approach for a few years now, and I must say, I have been impressed, by how easy it seed to maintain - until now!

In my new project, I seem to run in to problems, everytime I alter an Entity, which references other entities.

When I run the update-database -verbose function in the Packet-Manager Console, I seem to get the same error.

```
Cannot find the object xxxx because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

In my current case, I have a collection of Cars, and I wanted to add sort order to the collection, so I added a new class called CarSortPair, which takes a Car object, a SortOrder integer, and which has an ID also.

I have tried searching a lot on Google and StackOverflow, and there are different suggestions, and many of them suggest to run add-migration.

When I run add-migration carlist, i get this code into the automatically generated migration class.

```
public partial class carlist : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.CarListCars", newName: "CarListCarSortPairs");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.CarListCars", "Car_ID", "dbo.Cars");
        DropIndex("dbo.CarListCars", new[] { "Car_ID" });
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.CarSortPairs",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    SortOrder = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Car_ID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Cars", t => t.Car_ID)
            .Index(t => t.Car_ID);

        CreateIndex("dbo.CarListCarSortPairs", "CarSortPair_ID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.CarListCarSortPairs", "CarSortPair_ID", "dbo.CarSortPairs", "ID", cascadeDelete: true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.CarListCarSortPairs", "CarSortPair_ID", "dbo.CarSortPairs");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.CarSortPairs", "Car_ID", "dbo.Cars");
        DropIndex("dbo.CarListCarSortPairs", new[] { "CarSortPair_ID" });
        DropIndex("dbo.CarSortPairs", new[] { "Car_ID" });
        DropTable("dbo.CarSortPairs");
        CreateIndex("dbo.CarListCars", "Car_ID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.CarListCars", "Car_ID", "dbo.Cars", "ID", cascadeDelete: true);
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.CarListCarSortPairs", newName: "CarListCars");
    }
}
```

Which at first did not seem strange for me, but when I investigated it closer, I noticed, that the order of the script is not right!?

I tried to run update-database -verbose -script, which generated this script:

```
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.CarListCars', @newname = N'CarListCarSortPairs', @objtype = N'OBJECT'
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.CarListCars_dbo.Cars_Car_ID]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CarListCars] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.CarListCars_dbo.Cars_Car_ID]
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = N'IX_Car_ID' AND object_id = object_id(N'[dbo].[CarListCars]', N'U'))
    DROP INDEX [IX_Car_ID] ON [dbo].[CarListCars]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CarSortPairs] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [SortOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Car_ID] [int],
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.CarSortPairs] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_Car_ID] ON [dbo].[CarSortPairs]([Car_ID])
CREATE INDEX [IX_CarSortPair_ID] ON [dbo].[CarListCarSortPairs]([CarSortPair_ID])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CarListCarSortPairs] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.CarListCarSortPairs_dbo.CarSortPairs_CarSortPair_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([CarSortPair_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[CarSortPairs] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CarSortPairs] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.CarSortPairs_dbo.Cars_Car_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([Car_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Cars] ([ID])
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'201312100911087_AutomaticMigration', ......
```

Then I tried to execute the SQL script, line by line, and it indeed is executed in wrong order!

How can I fix this, in a way, that I can maintain my code easily. It does not make sense, if I need to maintain the scripts manually.

Edit: I have tried to update to EF 6.0.1 and the newest 6.0.2-beta2, to see if this was an error in the Entity Framework, but same result.

Comment: odd, but I have come across some weirdness with migrations before.  Why can you not just alter your migration file to be in the right order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks very like this issue described on codeplex: [Error in migration changing relation to "Many to Many"](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1885)

That issue is marked as "resolved" - in 6.1 - so a bit to wait yet